# Discord.js Get all members that have a specific role

Tags: node.js, discord.js, roles, member

I'm trying to get all members that have a specific role. Whenever I run the command I get only myself and the bot (if the bot has the role), but I have 4 other people in the server with the same role and none of them shows up. If I fetch all members they show up fine.

Anyone know why this happens?

Code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'add') {
        let list = client.guilds.cache.get("889906947711701022");
        let role1 = list.roles.cache.get('890636907904639027').members.map(m => m.user.id);
        console.log(role1);
    }
});
```

Console log:

```
[ '227896530835603458' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fetching all the members, your current output is only cached members.

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'add') {
        let list = client.guilds.cache.get("889906947711701022");

        try {
           await list.members.fetch();

           let role1 = list.roles.cache.get('890636907904639027').members.map(m => m.user.id);
           console.log(role1);
        } catch (err) {
           console.error(err);
        }
    }
});
```

You'll need to have the GuildMember's intent enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out this:

```js
let list = message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.get('890636907904639027'));
// console.log(list);
```

The `list` should have all guild members that have the role.

Comment: Shows "Collection(1) [Map] {" and the "1" is me. Doesnt make any sense :(