# Trying to get how many members with specific role discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I’m trying to count members of specific role but i’m getting error, message.guild.fetchMembers() is not a function

```
    let guild = await message.guild.fetchMembers();
    let roleID = '3933783737379';
    let memberCount = guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size;
    message.channel.send(memberCount + " members have this role!");
});
```

So if i just delete guild variable to make the code the code like this

```
let roleID = '3933783737379';
    let memberCount = message.guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size;
    message.channel.send(memberCount + " members have this role!");
```

He will count him self if he has it and count the owner only no one else counted

Is there any idea how to make this work?

Comment: I believe that this will solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304341/discord-js-get-all-members-that-have-a-specific-role

Comment: thanks for trying to help me but it still counting only 2 members only

Comment: Does it work if you change : let memberCount = guild.roles.get(roleID).members.size; to let memberCount = guild.roles.cache.get(roleID).members.size;?

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild.fetchMember();` is not a thing in discord.js v12.

> Discord.js v12 its `message.guild.members.fetch();`

Also `members.fetch();` returns a GuildMemberCollection -> [GuildMemberManager.fetch()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch)
not a guild object. Just await the fetch function and it should work with your second code! :)